# How to extract the on-click value

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a website that has a link to another website when clicked on the button. I want to get the name of that website.

The document contains:

```
<a class = "classA" onclick = "vendors_viewWebsite('http://www.somewebsite.com', '5454')" rel="nofollow" role="button"> Visit Website </a>
```

I would like to find `<a>` where there is a value for onclick and then check if there is *"http:"* in it and return the website's URL.

Is there a way to find that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your HTML is in a variable named  `soup`, you can use [soup.find_all(name, attrs, recursive, string, limit, **kwargs)](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all). Any non-mentioned keyword argument will be interpreted as an attribute (so, in your case, `onclick`), but we still need to find an acceptable range of values to provide.

To only return a result if there is "http://" or "https://" on it, we will need to create a regular expression. This regex would be `r"['\"](http(?:s?)://[^'\"]+)"`. You can see the explanation [here](https://regex101.com/r/gFeYlG/1). I am assuming that the URL does not contain the `'` or `"` characters, and either of such characters appears immediately before, and immediately after the URL.

Then, all we need is to apply the [re.compile(pattern)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) function, and we get:

```py
pattern = re.compile(r"['\"](http(?:s?)://[^'\"]+)"))

# Retrieve all elements containing the onclick attribute as desired
a_matches = soup.find_all("a", onclick=re.compile(r"['\"](http(?:s?)://[^'\"]+)"))

# Get just the URLs from the retrieved elements, by re-applying our regex
urls = [re.search(pattern, a["onclick"]).group(1) for a in a_matches]
```

[re.search(pattern, string) documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search). `group(1)` in the above code means that we're retrieving just the first capturing group in our regular expression, which is the part `(http(?:s?)://[^'\"]+)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below xpath.

```
//a[contains(@onclick,'http')]
```

**Script:**

```
# get the link with `http` in it's onclick attribute value
urlLink = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@onclick,'http')]")
print(urlLink.get_attribute("onclick"))
```

If you have multiple links on the page with `onclick` value then you can use

```
 urlElems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@onclick,'http')]")
 For urlElem in urlElems:
     print(urlElem.get_attribute("onclick"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use BeautifulSoup with CSS selector `a[onclick*="http"]` (select all `<a>` with `onclick` attribute containing `http`):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''
<a class = "classA" onclick = "vendors_viewWebsite('http://www.somewebsite.com', '5454')" rel="nofollow" role="button"> Visit Website </a>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.select('a[onclick*="http"]'):
    print(a['onclick'])
```

Prints:

```
vendors_viewWebsite('http://www.somewebsite.com', '5454')
```

Further reading:

**[CSS Selectors Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)**

Answer (score 0):

You can combine attribute = value css selectors to target the `onclick` and state the `onclick` must *contain* (*) `http:`  AND *start with* the string `vendors_viewWebsite`. This is hopefully more selective. Add a test for `if None`. split out the final url. For more more than one match use `select` as `select_one` returns first match only.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<a class = "classA" onclick = "vendors_viewWebsite('http://www.somewebsite.com', '5454')" rel="nofollow" role="button"> Visit Website </a>
'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
element = soup.select_one('[onclick^=vendors_viewWebsite][onclick*=http\:]')
if element is None:
    link = 'Not found'
else:
    link = element['onclick'].split("'")[1]
```

---

1. Developers reference: [css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

**Start with operator**

> [attr^=value]
>
> Represents elements with an attribute name of attr whose value is
>   prefixed (preceded) by value.

**Contains operator**

> [attr*=value]
>
> Represents elements with an attribute name of attr whose value
>   contains at least one occurrence of value within the string.